# Chrome Extension devtools_page Communication problem

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am getting confused with Chrome Extension devtools_page.
I want to send a command to the current websites Namespace and retrieve information from that page.

devtools_page JS file

```
//hey webpage, I know you have the Namespace ABC with the method collectData
```

webpage

```
let data = ABC.collectData;
return data;
```

devtools

```
// I got the data
```

Where do I add the communication in the extension to be able to get these data.
In the manifest I have "content_scripts" with "document_start"
And I have "web_accessible-resource" and the JS file from the "devtools_page".

And how do I instantiate the communication?

I tried so many different things and did not manage to get the communication up and running.

My best try was to use chrome.tabs.executeScript, but I cannot access the Namespace.

This is what I have so far:

a) executeScript

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'console.log("foo"); return true;
}, function(results) {
    console.log(results[0]);
});
```

Result: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_app.html?remoteBase=https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@326d148b9655369b86498d9ecca39f63dd2bdd2d/&can_dock=true&dockSide=undocked". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.`

b) devtools.inspectedWindow.eval

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
    "ABC.AllItems.all",
    function(result, isException) {
        if (isException)
            //==> I am getting here
    }
);
```

Result: `Object reference chain is too long`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of content scripts use chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval, [info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow). If you still want a content script then you need to dig a level deeper, see [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: thanks a lot, but it throws `Object reference chain is too long`

Comment: @wOxxOm I am trying to get all elements from a webpage - `Ext.ComponentManager.all` - into a custom view inside the chrome dev tools. I created a view (`chrome.devtools.panels.create`) and I am trying to communicate with the ExtJS webpage. I want to create an inspector for ExtJS.

Comment: Since this is inter-process communication you can't pass DOM elements. Only simple data.

Comment: I am only passing a huge JSON

Comment: Sounds like it may have circular references in which case it's not a JSON. Or maybe there's a bug in the API. Try passing JSON.stringify(ABC.AllItems.all)